# Find all primes $p$ for which $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}p$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

> Find all primes p for which the quotient $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}p$ is a perfect square.

It is a number theory problem. By guessing I found the value of $p$ is 3. But how do I prove it and how do I found the other primes?

Comment: Setting $p=2q+1$ is a good way to start.

Comment: $p=7$ is another solution

Comment: #Jack Frost ,if we put $p=2q+1$ then it becomes $\frac{4^q -1}{2q+1}$ and then .. What we can do with this di you have any idea

Comment: $4^q -1 = (2^q-1)(2^q+1)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put $p = 2q+1$, then the expression is $\dfrac{4^q-1}{2q+1} = \dfrac{(2^q-1)(2^q+1)}{2q+1}$.

Now, since $2^q-1$  and $2^q+1$ are co prime, one of them must be a perfect square. Let $(2^q-1)(2^q+1)=pm^2$. Then two cases arise, namely that :

1) $2^q-1 = px^2,2^q+1 = y^2$

2) $2^q-1 = x^2,2^q+1 = py^2$

For the first case, note that $(y-1)(y+1) = 2^q \implies y+1=2^m,y-1=2^n$, which gives $2^m-2^n=2$, giving $m=2,n=1$. This gives the case $q=3$ and $p=7$.

The second case is solved by the fact that $2^q - 1$ , if $q \geq 2$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, and hence cannot be a perfect square. So  this forces $q = 1$ to be checked, which gives $p = 3$ which works.

Comment: You reuse $m$ here which is slightly confusing.

Comment: How exactly does that _similar analysis_ work out? $py^2-1$ (unlike $y^2-1$) doesn't factor nicely; nor does $x^2+1$.

Comment: It's not really a "similar analysis," but if $2^q-1=x^2$, then if $q>1$ you have $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{4}$, which is impossible. So you only need to check $q=1,$ which is $p=3$. @IvanNeretin

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I never noticed that before! Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

With $p=2q+1$, such that $q\ge1$:
$$\frac{2^{p-1}-1}p=\frac{2^{2q}-1}p=\frac{(2^q+1)(2^q-1)}p$$
Note that $\gcd(2^q+1,2^q-1)=1$. This means the two terms in the numerator have no common prime factors and $p$ must divide exactly one of them, leaving the other to be a perfect square.

But by Mihăilescu's theorem, $2^q+1=m^2$ has only the solution $q=3$ and $2^q-1=m^2$ has only the solution $q=1$. Therefore $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}p$ can only be a perfect square for $p=3,7$, both primes, and indeed they are.
$$\frac{2^{3-1}-1}3=1^2,\ \frac{2^{7-1}-1}7=3^2$$

Comment: #Parcy Taxel : You did one  mistake in the first line $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}$ =$\frac{2^{2q}}{2q+1}$.You write it $\frac{2^{4q}}{2q+1}$

Comment: @SufaidSaleel ...whoops. Fixed.